# Unable to list windows shares from terminal

Tags: command-line, samba

I am unable to list windows shares from terminal. I am getting the following error,

```
root@ITSTA2:~# smbclient -L 172.XX.XX.XX -U john
params.c:Parameter() - Ignoring badly formed line in configuration file: # Samba config file
WARNING: The "Share modes" option is deprecated
Unknown parameter encountered: "read Size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "read Size"
Enter john's password: 
Unknown socket option SO_KEEPLIVE
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Someone sort out the problem pls..

Comment: There seem to be some errors in your `smb.conf` configuration file (e.g., there's a spelling error: `SO_KEEPLIVE` instead of `SO_KEEPALIVE`).  It's hard to tell anything more specific without seeing the actaul file; can you post it here or on some pastebin?

Comment: Sure i will paste my configuration file tonight..

Comment: My samba [configuration](http://paste.ubuntu.com/636163/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the remote machine to -L. If you want to force the use of a specific IP, pass it with -I.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a domain\\username notice the extra slash there. if I did an Alt-F2 and put in smb://Servername/sharename  I had to add a \ before the username.