# Samba Client and Windows 10 Home - "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE"/"Access denied"

Tags: samba, windows-10, shared-folders, smb, samba4

I'm trying to access a file share from a **Windows 10 Home** using a Samba client. However the following errors happen ...

**1# - smbclient**

```
[root@eduardo-nb eduardo]# smbclient -L 192.168.0.5 -W WORKGROUP -U eduardo
Enter WORKGROUP\eduardo's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

**2# - Dolphin**

[image: Access denied to smb://WORKGROUP%5Ceduardo@192.168.0.5/D.]

---

**NOTE:** The only way to gain access to the share is by following the procedures described here ...

[File Sharing not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-sharing-not-working/e6df6ac5-bb5a-41b3-8253-bd59b49d94bd)

... which consist of allowing access to "Everyone" and "Turn off password protected sharing".

**QUESTION:** I would like to access this share with my existing Windows 10 Home user (has administrative prerogatives)... **So what may be happening?**

Thanks! =D

[Refs.: [Unable to list windows shares from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/47291/134723) , [smbclient getting NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE connecting to Windows box](https://askubuntu.com/q/109507/134723) , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-sharing-not-working/e6df6ac5-bb5a-41b3-8253-bd59b49d94bd , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/samba-client-and-windows-10-home/a7502032-240a-4fc8-a756-132d46831adf?tm=1568998329476]

---

**UPDATE:** My `/etc/samba/smb.conf` ...

@harrymc

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Samba Server
   allow insecure wide links = yes
   printcap name = /etc/printcap
   load printers = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 50
   security = user
   dns proxy = no

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   writable = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   path = /var/spool/samba
   browseable = no
   guest ok = no
   writable = no
   printable = yes

[eduardo]
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   comment = Manjaro Linux Samba share
   path = /home/eduardo
   available = yes
   valid users = eduardo
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   public = no
   writeable = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE REAL PROBLEM:**

As you can see in this image...

[image: share issue]

...my user "eduardo" is actually "alldocube"... As seen in the print above the way the user "eduardo" ("alldocube") is in the system caused a huge confusion! Actually I couldn't understand how it happened...

**SOLUTION:**

So the only thing that needs to be done is to share (Properties > Sharing) drive "D" for the user "alldocube" (in my case) and give permissions (Properties > Security) on drive "D" for the user "alldocube".

To access the sharing using Linux open the file browser (Dolphin in my case) and in the path field enter `smb://WORKGROUP\<YOUR_USER>@<SERVER_IP>/<SHARE_NAME>` (`smb://WORKGROUP\alldocube@192.168.0.5/D` in my case).

[Ref.: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/samba-client-and-windows-10-home/a7502032-240a-4fc8-a756-132d46831adf?tm=1568998388625&auth=1&page=2 ]

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error running smbclient when you pass the wrong password.

So the question is is this a simple username and password in WIn10 or is it a Microsoft Account username and password as in eduardo@soemthing.com.

If you are using a Microsoft Account name then the smbclient command becomes:

```
smbclient -L 192.168.0.5 -W something.com -U eduardo
```

Comment: "this a simple username and password in WIn10" -> Yes! It is a simple username and password in Win10. "when you pass the wrong password" -> The password is correct. Same as I use to log in to Wind10. Thanks! =D